# Provable store an array

Tags: solidity, oracles, provable

I'm trying to understand some basis of Solidity,
I get how to get multiple values from one query, but don't really understand how to store them, could anyone explain me how to do it?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;
import "github.com/provable-things/ethereum-api/provableAPI_0.4.25.sol";

contract ExampleContract is usingProvable {

   string public ethprice;
   string public ethvolume;
   event LogConstructorInitiated(string nextStep);
   event LogPriceUpdated(string price);
   event LogNewProvableQuery(string description);

   function ExampleContract() payable {
       LogConstructorInitiated("Constructor was initiated. Call 'updatePrice()' to send the Provable Query.");
   }

   function __callback(bytes32 myid, string memory[] result) {
       if (msg.sender != provable_cbAddress()) revert();
       ethprice = result[0];
       ethvolume = result[1];
       LogPriceUpdated(result);
   }

   function updatePrice() payable {
       if (provable_getPrice("URL") > this.balance) {
           LogNewProvableQuery("Provable query was NOT sent, please add some ETH to cover for the query fee");
       } else {
           LogNewProvableQuery("Provable query was sent, standing by for the answer..");
           provable_query("URL", "json(https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/ETH-USD/ticker).[price,volume]");
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found some stuffs to tackle this issue:

The multiple query is store in a string, so it's easier to store the answer in one string first, which will be [price,volume] and split this string into an array of string at each comma thanks to :

```
strings.slice memory s = result.toSlice();                
        strings.slice memory delim = ",".toSlice();                            
        string[] memory parts = new string[](s.count(delim) + 1);                  
        for (uint i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {                              
           parts[i] = s.split(delim).toString();                              
        }
```

to get the array:

```
["[price","volume]"]
```

then to store the price and the volume in two different variable, we'll have to clean each part and remove the brackets thanks to:

```
function substring(string str, uint startIndex, uint endIndex) internal pure returns (string) {
    bytes memory strBytes = bytes(str);
    bytes memory cutted = new bytes(endIndex-startIndex);
    for(uint i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
        cutted[i-startIndex] = strBytes[i];
    }
    return string(cutted);
}
```

and to get a uint value and not a string:

```
function stringToUint(string s) internal pure returns (uint) {
    bytes memory b = bytes(s);
    uint result = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < b.length; i++) { 
        if (b[i] >= 48 && b[i] <= 57) {
            result = result * 10 + (uint(b[i]) - 48);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

so we'll have at the end:

```
price = stringToUint(substring(parts[0], 2 , parts[0].toSlice().len() - 1));
volume = stringToUint(substring(parts[1], 1 , parts[1].toSlice().len() - 2));
```

and that's it, even if I do believe it's a bit unnecessarily complicated and an easier and simplier solution must exist, but this does work at least, and that's all I could find.